# Thread and UI in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

This is XAML with a button and 3 progress bars

TestBtn

this is the thread to update the 3 progress bars..

```
Thread thread = new Thread(
                                new ThreadStart(
                                    delegate()
                                    {
                                        progressBar1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                                                        new Action(
                                                                                            delegate()
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                int x=0;
                                                                                                while(true)
                                                                                                {

                                                                                                    x++;
                                                                                                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                                                                                                progressBar1.Value = x;
                                                                                                    if (x>100)
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        break;
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                MessageBox.Show(" Complete ");
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    ));


                                        progressBar2.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                                                        new Action(
                                                                                            delegate()
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                int y = 0;
                                                                                                while (true)
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                                                                                                    y = y + 2;
                                                                                                    progressBar2.Value = y;
                                                                                                    if (y > 100)
                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                        break;
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                                MessageBox.Show(" Complete ");
                                                                                            }
                                                                                    ));



                                        progressBar3.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                                                                       new Action(
                                                                                           delegate()
                                                                                           {

                                                                                               int z = 0;
                                                                                               while (true)
                                                                                               {
                                                                                                   Thread.Sleep(50);
                                                                                                   z = z + 3;
                                                                                                   progressBar3.Value = z;
                                                                                                   if (z > 100)
                                                                                                   {
                                                                                                       break;
                                                                                                   }
                                                                                               }
                                                                                               MessageBox.Show(" Complete ");
                                                                                           }
                                                                                   ));
 )
            );//end of thread

            thread.Start();

        }
```

when i run this, all the 3 progress bars are updated to 100 percent at last(all are reaching directly to 100 at the same time) and it is not showing any increments from 0 to 100.

What  i need is a thread with  3 item , where each will update the UI at the same time.So here at the same time all these 3 progress bars have to start and they have finish according to the loop..
(When we are copying files, in the UI , copying description is changing at  the same time progress bar has to be updated.I want similar to that.So i think if i can understand a small example like this, then i can sort the required one)

Comment: Please edit and repaste your code.

Comment: this is the code in XAML..if u want anymore details let me know..sorru 4 delay...

<Grid>
        <Button Height="23" Margin="90,0,114,7" Name="Btn1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Btn1_Click">TestBtn</Button>
        <ProgressBar Foreground="Blue" Height="25" Margin="35,53,44,0" Name="progressBar1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ProgressBar Foreground="Yellow" Height="25" Margin="35,88,44,0" Name="progressBar2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ProgressBar Foreground="Black" Margin="35,125,44,112" Name="progressBar3" />
    </Grid>

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a `BackgroundWorker`, example by [Figo Fei](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/d7a1c9d3-e69b-4b0f-b386-11ba2f2c1fbb) (altered slightly):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // This would be the load process, where you put your Load methods into.
    // You would report progress as something loads.

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i); //run in back thread
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) //call back method
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) //call back method
{
    progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
}
```

One of the lovely thing about the BackgroundWorker is that it does run all the "heavy lifting" on a worker thread, but reports back to the UI thread. So by using the above code to your own needs, you should solve your problem.

Comment: Hai Kyle,
Thank you for your help..i could able to find the solution for your problem with this one...:)
Kaja

Comment: A pleasure Kaja, if this does indeed work for you, please remember to mark this as the answer. Cheers, Kyle.